# ActiveMQ embedded with MQTT and Default MQ enabled, Possible to publish to both in one call?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ embedded in Glassfish with both the default 61616 communication port and a port with MQTT enabled.

Is there a way to publish to both of these MQs in one call if ActiveMQ is configured a certain way?

If not, is the only way to connect to the MQTT server from the J2EE server through a 3rd party MQTT client?

If so, is there a MQTT lib that can take advantage of J2EE container's connection pools?

Answer (score 0):

All protocols in ActiveMQ will share the same topics and queues.

You can subscribe and publish as you wish from java/JMS and the data will be accessible on the same topic using MQTT.

Of course, there will be some issues if you use JMS-only features, such as ObjectMessage and whatnot, but that is pretty obvious. Stick to text messages on topics and you should be fine.